# How to return ordered data from multiple records into one record in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, group-concat

I have a MySQL database with a table of survey responses with three important fields (renamed for clarity): SURVEY_TAKER_ID, QUESTION_NUMBER, and RESPONSE. Assuming a 3-question survey as an example, it would look something like this:

```
SURVEY_TAKER_ID | QUESTION_NUMBER | RESPONSE
----------------------------------------
101               1                 Apple
102               1                 Orange
103               1                 Banana
101               2                 Morning
102               2                 Evening
103               2                 Afternoon
101               3                 Red
102               3                 Blue
103               3                 Yellow
```

I would like to create a SELECT query that outputs each survey taker's ID and responses in order by question number, e.g.:

```
101,Apple,Morning,Red
102,Orange,Evening,Blue
103,Banana,Afternoon,Yellow
```

I know that SQL Server has `FOR XML`, which can make this easier, but my database is in MySQL, and I must admit that I'm not really all that adept at SQL in the first place. Can anyone please give me a sample query that would produce the output above, or point me to a way to do it?

Many thanks to anyone who can help...

...Jay

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Pointing you to a way to do it ==> http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SURVEY_TAKER_ID with "Question_Number: RESPONSE" style concating:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2745/15)

```
SELECT SURVEY_TAKER_ID
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(QUESTION_NUMBER, ': ', RESPONSE) ORDER BY QUESTION_NUMBER SEPARATOR ', ') AS RESPONSES
FROM Table1
GROUP BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID
ORDER BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID
```

.

**SURVEY_TAKER_ID with "RESPONSE" alone style concating:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2745/17)

```
SELECT SURVEY_TAKER_ID
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(RESPONSE ORDER BY QUESTION_NUMBER SEPARATOR ', ') AS RESPONSES
FROM Table1
GROUP BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID
ORDER BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Bill. I'll give those a try and report back!

Comment: Hi Bill. Thanks so much for doing this. From looking at the SQL Fiddle output, my only concern is that there's no control in there to make sure that the `RESPONSE` output is ordered by `QUESTION_NUMBER`. Is there a way to add that in? I tried putting an `ORDER BY` clause into the parentheses after `RESPONSE SEPARATOR`, but SQL Fiddle threw an error.

Comment: Hey, Jay. I believe you may have been putting the ORDER BY in the CONCAT function rather that the GROUP_CONCAT. My first code block has a CONCAT imbedded inside the GROUP_CONCAT. I updated my answer with ORDER BYs that appear to work and linked to the new fiddle URSs. I also ordered the outer results by SURVEY_tAKER_ID.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. I've got it now: `SELECT SURVEY_TAKER_ID
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(RESPONSE ORDER BY QUESTION_NUMBER ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS RESPONSES
FROM Table1
GROUP BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID` Thanks for your help! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SURVEY_TAKER_ID, ',', RESPONSE)
FROM (SELECT SURVEY_TAKER_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(RESPONSE) RESPONSE
      FROM (SELECT * FROM SURVEY ORDER BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID, QUESTION_NUMBER) A 
      GROUP BY SURVEY_TAKER_ID
     ) A
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Saharsh. I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Hi Saharsh. Thanks, but that puts all of the responses to a given question in each record. I was trying to put all of the responses for each survey_taker in each record. I appreciate your help, though!

Comment: @JayinNJ Check my updated answer. I had changed the group by clause from `QUESTION_NUMBER` to `SURVEY_TAKER_ID`