# Return product from order data from multiple record to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database which contains survey data and is very close to this question [How to return ordered data from multiple records into one record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778803/how-to-return-ordered-data-from-multiple-records-into-one-record-in-mysql)

The data is almost identical. Again copied from the above question but with addition of millisecond and `datetime2` column.

```
SURVEY_TAKER_ID | QUESTION_NUMBER | RESPONSE
----------------+-----------------+-----------
101               1                 Apple
102               1                 Orange
103               1                 Banana
101               2                 Morning
102               2                 Evening
103               2                 Afternoon
101               3                 Red
102               3                 Blue
103               3                 Yellow
```

I am trying to use group by function but it is not grouping responses but showing responses in rows format.

```
select 
    s.survey_taker_ID, AVG(s.Millisecond)Duration, 
    (case when s.Question_Number = 1 then s.Answer end Product1,
    (case when s.Question_Number = 2 then s.Answer end Product2
from 
    survey as s
group by 
    s.survey_taker_ID,  s.Question_Number,s.Answer
```

Output:

```
Survey_Taker_ID | Duration | Product1  | Product2 
----------------+----------+-----------+----------
    101         |  11125   | Apple     | Morning
    102         |  12545   | Orange    | Evening
```

Sad part is I have done this before but cannot seem to achieve it now. I know i am making some stupid mistake. Any sample code will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select s.survey_taker_ID, AVG(s.Millisecond) as Duration, 
       max(case when s.Question_Number = 1 then s.Answer end) as Product1,
       max(case when s.Question_Number = 2 then s.Answer end) as Product2
from survey as s
group by s.survey_taker_ID;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing. Thank you so much.